# How to change view when tapping button in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, button, swift, uiviewcontroller

Usually, I change view like this:

```
var goBackToMainView:MainViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation2") as MainViewController

self.presentViewController(goBackToMainView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But if I try to do this in my custom UITableViewCell when the user tap a button, it gives me errors like `customTableViewCell does not have a member named 'storyboard' and 'presentViewController'`

How can I change views in my TableViewCell ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding as a subview?

Example:

```
var tableViewCell = UITableViewCell(frame: aFrame)

tableViewCell.addSubview(aView)
```

Comment: And how do i get aView if i can't use `self.storyboard` ?

Comment: so your tableViewCell is from the storyboard? Where are you creating the 'child' views that you want to add/change to/in the UITableViewCell?

Comment: I create the other view in the storyboard

Comment: have you created the link to the StoryBoard in the UITableViewCell? like...
`var storyboard = UIStoryBoard(storyboardWithName: "something", bundle: nil)`

Comment: Thanks now i have the storyboard variable working now what do i have to do to get the presentViewController function

Answer (score 1):

Why do it in the UITableViewCell subclass? You should be doing your view management in the ViewController.

In your view controller:

```
import UIKit

// Take note of UITableViewDelegate, you'll need it to be able to use
// tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Assuming that you have a storyboard variable in AppDelegate
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    // .. more code here like viewDidLoad, etc.

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var viewController = appDelegate.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as MainViewController

        // This will probably appear as a modal
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Note: I just did a quick playground for the code above so you may need to unwrap optionals.

If you have your view controller embedded in a navigation controller, you might want to use Unwind Segues. More information about that here: [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Cheers!

Comment: Cause i wan't it to change view it the user tap the button not the cell